Exporting a raster in QGIS to a given resolution in degrees
I have a raster I would like to save in QGIS to a different resolution. The problem is that the resolution I want to use is 3.75 arcsec, and if I try to save the raster in QGIS I can only enter a decimal resolution.
This resolution comes out to 0.001041666... degrees repeating, but I want to export it to exactly 3.75 arcsec, and if I try to write as many digits as possible, it still won't be exactly this value.
Is there any way to save a raster in QGIS by entering degrees in minutes and seconds rather than decimals?

You should resample to your desired resolution

Some real values cannot be represented in floating-point representation 3.75/3600 is one of those values. Both 3.75/60 and 3.75 can be stored exactly, so you'd have to use units of decimal minutes or decimal seconds.
